# ng-repeat specify a starting index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I specify an index where an ng-repeat directive is going to start instead of zero?

I have a set of results and I just need to specify the starting one, which is different from zero.

Comment: If you need to sort or modify your result set consider using a filter.

Answer (score 58):

No need to code anything, angular has done this with the *existing* built-in [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter.  Just use a negative limit. From the docs for the `limit` argument:

> The length of the returned array or string. If the limit number is
>   positive, limit number of items from the beginning of the source
>   array/string are copied. **If the number is negative, limit number of
>   items from the end of the source array/string are copied**. The limit
>   will be trimmed if it exceeds array.length. If limit is undefined, the
>   input will be returned unchanged.

So you would use it like so in the template:

```
<ul>
   <li data-ng-repeat="i in list | limitTo: (offset - list.length)">{{i}}</li>
</ul>
```

where `offset` is your start index. See sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zA1Euilh6CwzjlGstqMn?p=preview).

There is an optional `begin` argument so you don't need use a negative `limit` but the `begin` was not available before angular v1.4 so I have stuck to a negative `limit` in my example.

Comment: the most elegant solution! Thanks!

Comment: there's a problem to use $index value (for example to remove element from list) some advice? (i use [$index + offset] but i looking for a better way to do that)

Comment: @SilvioTroia I normally avoid using $index to index an element in the list because it's an index of what is displayed and not an index into the array if that makes sense. For delete I would do something like `list.splice(list.indexOf(i), 1)` where `i` is the element in the list you want to delete.

Answer (score 43):

The answers seems to be quite old,

since angular `1.4.0` the limitTo filter takes two parameters

`limitTo: (limit) : (begin)`

you can say `ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo:50:0"`

this seems to be a much effective solution rather using two different filters.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for a better solution now I've found one, thanks to you. Anyone interested into the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo IMHO this should be mentioned here too https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: This should be the selected answer as of AngualrJS v1.4+.

Answer (score 38):

You can create a filter

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

and then you just use it on the ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | startFrom : 2">{{item.Name}}</div>
```

Comment: Where do you put `app.filter`? in controller.js or app.js?

Comment: "the" app variable is that one variable you get from calling angular.module()
Seemingly

Comment: great solution nice and modular.

Answer (score 32):

Say you have a list of `items`, you can do it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index >= myIndex">
   {{item.Name}}
</div>
```

Comment: This one remove an element, I want to resort them and start form a different one than 0.

Comment: @FedericoVezzoli If you need to resort then I suggest you iterate on a different object, do the sorting in the controller, or maybe a filter as others have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a function that returns the desire subarray. This can go in the controller or the link function of a directive.

```
<span ng-repeat="item in getSubArray(0, 4)">...</span>
```

And the function

```
$scope.getSubArray = function (start, end) {
   return array.slice(start, end);
}
```

Comment: I should say that the filter from Emanuel is a better solution because is more reusable

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<element ng-repeat="round in view.rounds track by $index">
    <span>{{$index + 1}}</span>
</element>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could do the trick...

```
<div ng-repeat="(i, item) in items">
    <p>{{i+1}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple but not so attractive way

```
 ng-repeat="item in model | limitTo: 10 | limitTo: -5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result of what I was looking for:

```
angular.module('starter.filters', []).filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    if(input) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        appended = input.slice(0,start);
        initialArray = input.slice(start);
        finalArray= initialArray.concat(appended);
        return finalArray;
    }
    return [];
}
});
```

thanks [@emanuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895611/emanuel-ralha)