# Is it possible to have ng-repeat start at the nth element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects which I'm using to populate an HTML table. The first 3 elements of the array are to be handled differently from the rest of the elements.

So what I'd like to have is something like this:

```
<td>Special formatting for element 0: {{myObjArray[0].myProperty}}</td>
<td>Special formatting for element 1: {{myObjArray[1].myProperty}}</td>
<td>Special formatting for element 2: {{myObjArray[2].myProperty}}</td>
<td ng-repeat="myObj in myObjArray starting at element 3">{{myObj.myProperty}}</td>
```

Comment: check the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411220/ng-repeat-specify-a-starting-index

Comment: or `ng-if="$index > 2"`.  No filter needed.

Answer (score 0):

check [this code snippet](https://gist.github.com/svenanders/7289017). It creates a custom filter to apply with `ng-repeat` with defined start and end for a given array. for example:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in array|limitFromTo:2:8"></div>
```

Comment: This could work if I knew how many elements were in the array, but I don't. Also, for my particular situation, copying arrays can be expensive.