# How to append div to previous div if their id's match (ANGULAR JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is how my layout looks like in html

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <div ng-class="{'messages messages--sent': userId == message.id,         
        'messages messages--received': userId != message.id}">
            <div class="message">
                {{message.content}}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the structure of my messages array

```
    $scope.messages = [
    {
        "id":"Michael",
        "content":"Hey"
    },
    {
        "id":"Rich",
        "content":"Yow"
    },
    {
        "id":"Rich",
        "content":"How are you"
    },
    {
        "id":"Michael",
        "content":"Im okay"
    },
    {
        "id":"Michael",
        "content":"Im missed you!"
    },
    ];
```

[This is the layout I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlSLF.png)

The previous layout follows this css code styling

```
.messages--received .message:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
}

.messages--received .message:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.messages--received .message:last-child::after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background: url(profile.png) center center no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -35px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.messages--sent .message {
    float: right;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: #1998e6;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.messages--sent .message:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
}

.messages--sent .message:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[But this is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fv2q.png)

My problem is it creates a new div every loop during ng-repeat, and I dont want that. To achieve that layout I want to append the next {{message.content}} to the previously created div if both of their {{message.id}} matches.

Else if they dont match, just create a new div like usual.
Please help thanks :)

Note: I dont want to filter it and group everything, I previously posted a question but most people misunderstood it so I posted some photos this time for a clearer understanding. THANKSSSS ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The way you've described is probably not the best way to handle but here it is:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-if="message.id != messages[$index - 1].id" style="border:1px solid red">
    <div >
            <div class="message">
                {{message.content}} - {{$index}}
            </div>
    </div>
  <hr>
    <div  
        ng-repeat="nextMessage in messages | startFrom : $parent.$index + 1"
         ng-if="nextMessage.id == messages[$parent.$index].id && ($index == 0 || nextMessage.id == messages[$index-1].id)" style="border:1px solid blue"
        >
            <div class="message">
                {{nextMessage.content}} - {{$index}}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and an ng-repeat start index filter [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411220/ng-repeat-specify-a-starting-index):

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

Two `ng-if`-s added. One on ng-repeat to skip an iteration which has matching id with previous iteration and one inside to show the next items with matching id-s amd a nested ngrepeat to add to the current container div every subsequent message with the same id until a different id is present.

Of course, you can integrate the first inner div in the ng-repeat too, but I leave it separate now.

And the fiddle without the css part, showing the grouped messages with red: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/Qvzzed

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this, if its okay and if I'm not being a bother :3