# Move all child of ng-repeat and show new

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello I need to create animation which gonna move all items displayed by `ng-repeat` directive to the left, hide the first one and show new element in place of the last one.

Element are displayed by `ng-repeat` directive from JSON object in controller.

```
<div class="element" ng-repeat="n in elements | limitTo: 4">
  {{n.title}}
</div>
```

it is limited to 4 element although it has 5 element in JSON object inside controller:

```
$scope.elements = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'title1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'title3'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'title4'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'title5'
  }
]
```

So in brief: 
after clicking **>** sign on the right of all element I want to hide first one, move all to the left and show new one on the right.

How to do so? Here's plunker on which I was working on and you guys can use it:
https://plnkr.co/edit/dmmrNMaBno3KZMqL8E6O?p=preview

Comment: better use plugin then write code for it. here is a plugin which will give almost same as you want  https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html

Comment: yeah that's exacly what I want but its using jQuery I don't really want to inject big file (jQ) to my angularJS project only for this one script. Do you know some same plugin written in angularJS or vanilla JS? EDIT: Ok I found this one: https://mihnsen.github.io/ui-carousel/

Comment: what how jquery became big file. i think you have not read the installation documentation. you only need one js file, two css file and jquery

Comment: minified and gzipped jQuery file weight almost 90 kB it's pointless to inject jQuery into big project just to use in once..

Comment: lol. are you comedy me. you can do lots of things with jquery. if its a big project why dont you use jquery. i guarantee you will need jquery in future

Comment: You haven't even attempted any implementation of your `moveSlide()` function. Here's a tip: look into [manipulating the start index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411220/ng-repeat-specify-a-starting-index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all you could make your life easier with some external plugin that does exactly this, but if you want to have your own solution, I played around and made it without jQuery. Most of magic is in CSS and some in javascript. Also I've put everything in directive since all DOM manipulation should be done in directives. You could improve this a bit of course:

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {

});
app.directive('elements', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'element.html',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.elements = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'title1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        title: 'title2'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        title: 'title3'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        title: 'title4'
      }, {
        id: 5,
        title: 'title5'
      }, {
        id: 6,
        title: 'title6'
      },{
        id: 7,
        title: 'title7'
      }, {
        id: 8,
        title: 'title8'
      }, {
        id: 9,
        title: 'title9'
      }, {
        id: 10,
        title: 'title10'
      }, {
        id: 11,
        title: 'title11'
      }, {
        id: 12,
        title: 'title12'
      }]

      let elementPos = 0;

      $scope.moveSlide = () => {
        elementPos+=4;
        document.querySelectorAll(".element").forEach(elem => {
          let element = angular.element(elem);
          if (elementPos>=$scope.elements.length){
            document.querySelectorAll(".element").forEach(elem => angular.element(elem).css('margin-left', '15px'));
            elementPos=0;
            return;
          }else if (elementPos >= element.attr('order')){
            element.css('margin-left', '-100px');  
          }
        });

      }
    }
  }
});
```

**element.html**

```
<div class="left-arrow"> &lt; </div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element-container" style="width:{{elements.length*115}}px">
    <div class="element" order="{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="n in elements">
      {{n.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right-arrow" ng-click="moveSlide()"> &gt; </div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" >
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <elements></elements>


</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 475px;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-arrow {
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  top:-50px;
}

.right-arrow {
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  top:-50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could you extend this script of scrolling to the left if u have already clicked `>` button?

Comment: You can improve but this is doing it: https://plnkr.co/edit/49kssTAKDigTi7Aw82Fy?p=preview